# How to write Cypress tests for a product with 2 web pages?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I need to create automation from scratch with JS & Cypress.
My system consists of 2 different web pages: 1st is like word press, where i perform the changes \ design the website, while the 2nd is the website where i see the changes i did and need to do there all my assertions.
Since Cypress does not support multiple tabs, who knows how would it be possible to automate such scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both pages are the same. The first one is the development version.
The second one is the production version. Automate the development version website first.
Run the script and confirm that the script runs successfully. Then, change the url in the script to point to production version website. Rerun the same script in the production version. Confirm that the script runs without errors on both versions. You don't need to test multiple tabs.

Comment: Thank you DktPhl2018 for your answer.
Both are development environment just 1 is to perform changes on the website, second is to verify. Production is much later after CI process.
And by doing changes and in order to verify them, I'm not sure that Cypress "remembers" steps done (unlike JAVA that is possible)

Comment: In Cypress just like in Java, you first write steps like open this screen, click on this button, etc. Cypress is not different from Java where you need to specifically code steps to perform. What you code is what Cypress will do. For your first question, I just mean to test in both environments. It does not need to be production.

Answer (score 0):

Write the tests for design as precondition tests and then write the real tests for second web site to verify that changes apply.